# ASP.NET Web API custom media type versioning and controllers

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for some feedback on implementing support for media types in ASP.NET Web API. This is not the normal question about how to get a media type like 'application/vnd.company.myapp.v1+json' to map to a v1 controller. That is already documented all over the place.

My question: how do you create a Web API model with core metadata (Id, Title, ...) and allow for additional properties based on media type (e.g., application/vnd.company.myapp.doc.v1+json,   application/vnd.company.myapp.invoice.v1+json, ...) without having to create a direct controller to media type match. I would like to have a controller that can handle documents of various schemas, but with a consistent core set of properties. I would ultimately like to be able to register code to handle new type of document variations without needing to create a new controller each time.

I thought about creating a model with properties (Id, Title, ...) and a dynamic property that could contain the other document variations. Am I just coming at this all wrong?

Any ideas are welcome.